# which is optimal a bigger block cache size or a smaller one?

Tags: algorithm, caching, optimization, cpu-architecture

Given a cache size with constant capacity and associativity, for a given code to determine average of array elements, would a cache with higher block size be preferred?

[from comments]

Examine the code given below to compute the average of an array:

```
total = 0; 
for(j=0; j < k; j++) { 
  sub_total = 0; /* Nested loops to avoid overflow */ 
  for(i=0; i < N; i++) { 
    sub_total += A[jN + i]; 
  } 
  total += sub_total/N; 
} 
average = total/k;
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Can you give us an example? Typically, the response to "what size of cache is better" questions is, "It depends on your data and access pattern."

Comment: Examine the code given below to compute the average of an array:
total = 0;
for(j=0; j < k; j++) {
sub_total = 0;
/* Nested loops 
to avoid overflow */
for(i=0; i < N; i++) {
sub_total += A[j*N + i];
}
total += sub_total/N;
}
average = total/k;

Comment: Edit your question and put the code there, preferably formatted for readability. Can't make sense of code in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Related: in the more general case of typical access patterns with some but limited spatial locality, larger lines help up to a point.  These **["Memory Hierarchy: Set-Associative Cache"](http://cse.unl.edu/~jiang/cse430/Lecture%20Notes/reference-ppt-slides/Memory-Cache1.ppt)** (powerpoint) slides by Hong Jiang and/or Yifeng Zhu (U. Maine) have a graph of AMAT (Average Memory Access Time) vs. block size showing a curve, and also breaking it down into miss penalty vs. miss rate (for a simple model I think, for a simple in-order CPU that sucks at hiding memory latency. e.g. maybe not even pipelining multiple independent misses. (miss under miss))

There is a *lot* of good stuff in those slides, including a compiler-optimization section that mentions loop interchange (to fix nested loops with column-major vs. row-major order), and even cache-blocking for more reuse.  A lot of stuff on the Internet is crap, but I looked through these slides and they have some solid info on how caches are designed and what the tradeoffs are.  The performance-analysis stuff is only really accurate for simple CPUs, not like modern out-of-order CPUs that can overlap some computation with cache-miss latency so more shorter misses is different from fewer longer misses.

---

**Specific answer to this question**:

**So the only workload you care about is a linear traversal of your elements**?  That makes cache line size nearly irrelevant for performance, assuming good hardware prefetching.  (So larger lines mean less HW complexity and power usage for the same performance.)

With software prefetch, larger lines mean less prefetch overhead (although depending on the CPU design, that may not hurt performance if you still max out memory bandwidth.)

Without any prefetching, a larger line/block size would mean more hits following every demand-miss.  A single traversal of an array has perfect spatial locality and no temporal locality.  (Actually not quite perfect spatial locality at the start/end, if the array isn't aligned to the start of a cache line, and/or ends in the middle of a line.)

If a miss has to wait until the entire line is present in cache before the load that caused the miss can be satisfied, this slightly reduces the advantage of larger blocks.  (But most of the latency of a cache miss is in the signalling and request overhead, not in waiting for the burst transfer to complete after it's already started.)

A larger block size means fewer requests in flight with the same bandwidth and latency, and limited concurrency is a real limiting factor in memory bandwidth in real CPUs.  (See the [latency-bound platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy) part of this answer about x86 memory bandwidth: many-core Xeons with higher latency to L3 cache have lower single-threaded bandwidth than a dual or quad-core of the same clock speed.  Each core only has 10 line-fill buffers to track outstanding L1 misses, and `bandwidth = concurrency / latency`.)

If your cache-miss handling has an **early restart** design, even that bit of extra latency can be avoided.  (That's very common, but Paul says [theoretically possible to not have it in a CPU design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546454/which-is-optimal-a-bigger-block-cache-size-or-a-smaller-one#comment80061998_46551449)).  The load that caused the miss gets its data as soon as it arrives.  The rest of the cache line fill happens "in the background", and hopefully later loads can also be satisfied from the partially-received cache line.

[**Critical word first**](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/cmsc411/website/projects/ramguide/cache/cache.html#ercwf) is a related feature, where the needed word is sent first (for use with early restart), and the burst transfer then wraps around to transfer the earlier words of the block.  In this case, the critical word will always be the first word, so no special hardware support is needed beyond early restart.  (The U. Maine slides I linked above mention early restart / critical word first and point out that it decreases the miss penalty for large cache lines.)

---

An out-of-order execution CPU (or software pipelining on an in-order CPU) could give you the equivalent of HW prefetch by having multiple demand-misses outstanding at once.  If the CPU "sees" the loads to another cache line while a miss to the current cache line is still outstanding, the demand-misses can be pipelined, again hiding some of the difference between larger or smaller lines.

If lines are too small, you'll run into a limit on how many outstanding misses for different lines your L1D can track.  With larger lines or smaller out-of-order windows, you might have some "slack" when there's no outstanding request for the next cache line, so you're not maxing out the bandwidth.  And you pay for it with bubbles in the pipeline when you get to the end of a cache line and the start of the next line hasn't arrived yet, because it started too late (while ALU execution units were using data from too close to the end of the current cache line.)

---

Related: [these slides](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2013sp/lecture/18-caches3-w.pdf) don't say much about the tradeoff of larger vs. smaller lines, but look pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

The simplistic answer is that larger cache blocks would be preferred since the workload has no (data) temporal locality (no data reuse), perfect spacial locality (excluding the potentially inadequate alignment of the array for the first block and insufficient size of the array for the last block, every part of every block of data will be used), and a single access stream (no potential for conflict misses).

A more nuanced answer would consider the size and alignment of the array (the fraction of the first and last cache blocks that will be unused and what fraction of the memory transfer time that represents; for a 1 GiB array, even 4 KiB blocks would waste less than 0.0008% of the memory bandwidth), the ability of the system to use critical word first (if the array is of modest size and there is no support for early use of data as it becomes available rather than waiting for the entire block to be filled, then the start-up overhead will remove much of the prefetching advantage of larger cache blocks), the use of prefetching (software or hardware prefetching reduces the benefit of large cache blocks and this workload is extremely friendly to prefetching), the configuration of the memory system (e.g., using DRAM with an immediate page close controller policy would increase the benefit of larger cache blocks because each access would involve a row activate and row close, often to the same DRAM bank preventing latency overlap), whether the same block size is used for instructions and page table accesses and whether these accesses share the cache (instruction accesses provide a second "stream" which can introduce conflict misses; with shared caching of a two-level hierarchical page table TLB misses would access two cache blocks), whether simple way prediction is used (a larger block would increase prediction accuracy reducing misprediction overhead), and perhaps other factors.

Comment: Wouldn't instruction fetch keep the instructions in the MRU position in your unified-L1 example?  Amusing idea, though.  In my answer, I wasn't sure if simple designs ever have to wait for the whole cache line to arrive before satisfying a load for the first word.  (i.e. not even behaving like critical-word first  when the critical word is the first one.)  That would reduce the advantage of larger lines, but only slightly because a lot of the latency is setting up the request (and DRAM signals), not waiting for the actual burst transfer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah (though a loop buffer might complicate things as might vector instructions and deep pipelining). It is *theoretically* possible for a system not to support early restart; there *might* even be a small energy-efficiency benefit to waiting. (I also did not consider sectored cache blocks, which can reduce the refill latency, or the impact on DRAM burst length.) Such homework-like exercises are more interesting in grasping what they assume (e.g., no prefetching) to provide a simple model for beginning students than in providing the expected answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's funny how non-simple modern real-world desktop CPUs are.  That reminds me of the infamous ["deoptimizing a C++ program (for Haswell)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37361145/224132) question, which asks "use your knowledge of how the Intel i7 pipeline operates. Imagine ways to re-order instruction paths to introduce WAR, RAW, and other hazards."  But of course register renaming means no WAR or WAW hazards, as my answer explained :P 
 Interestingly, the professor who assigned it actually posted about it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323690/224132

Comment: Makes me wonder what they were actually taught, and whether it was more like a classic-RISC pipeline than an actual Intel i7 pipeline!  Still a fun answer to write, but probably not much like what the professor thought the right answers would be.

Answer (score 0):

From your example code we can't say either way as long as the hardware pre-fetcher can keep up a memory stream at maximum memory throughput.

In a random access scenario a shorter cache-line might be preferable as you then don't need to fill all the line. But the total amount of cached memory would go down as you need more circuits for tags and potentially more time for comparing.

So a compromise must be made Intel has chosen 64-bytes per line (and fetches 2 lines) others has chosen 32-bytes per line.