# if cache miss happens, the data will be moved to register directly or first moved to cache then to register?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, cpu-cache

if cache miss happens, the data will be moved to register directly from main memory,  or the data firstly will be moved to cache then to register? Is there a direct way connect the register with main memory?

Comment: When you say "moved to register directly from main memory", do you really mean "copied to register directly from main memory, and *also* copied to the cache"? Otherwise, what use is the cache? And bypassing the cache will generally make your program slower (as direct memory access is slower than the cache). And can you please elaborate on *why* you want to bypass the cache? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? What is the use-case?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I means that in the circuit, is putting the data to registers  the same time as putting the data in cache? I know the data will be put in cache(LLC, L2, L1), but I care about that is there a sequence between putting data to registers with putting data to cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking if a cache-miss load has to wait for L1 load-use latency after the cache line arrives from outer cache.  i.e. wait for the line to be written to L1, then retry the load normally.

I'm almost certain that high-performance CPUs don't work that way.  L2-hit latency is important for many workloads, and you need a load buffer tracking that incoming cache line anyway to know when to restart the load.  So you just grab the data as it comes in, in parallel with writing it to the cache.  The TLB check was already done as part of generating a physical address to send to the outer cache.

Most real CPUs use an early-restart design that lets the pipeline restart as soon as the word / byte they were waiting for arrives, so the rest of the cache line transfers "in the background".

A further optimization is critical-word-first, which asks for the cache line to be sent starting with the needed word, so a demand miss for a word in the middle of a cache line can receive that word first.  I think modern DDR DRAM still supports this when reading from main memory, starting the 64-byte burst at a specified 64-bit chunk.  I'm not 100% sure modern out-of-order CPUs use this, though; when out-of-order execution allows multiple outstanding misses for the same line, it probably makes it more complicated.

See [which is optimal a bigger block cache size or a smaller one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546454/which-is-optimal-a-bigger-block-cache-size-or-a-smaller-one) for some discussion of early-restart and critical-word-first.

---

> Is there a direct way connect the register with main memory?

It depends what you mean by "direct".  In a modern high-performance CPU, there will be 2 or 3 layers of cache and a memory controller with its own buffering to arbitrate access to memory for multiple cores.  So no, you can't.

If you design a simple single-core CPU with special cache-bypassing load and store instructions, then sure.  Or if you consider early-restart as "direct", then yes it already happens.

For stores, x86 and some other architectures have cache-bypassing stores, but x86's MOVNT instructions don't directly connect registers with memory.  Stores go into a line-fill buffer which is flushed when full, so you get write-combining.

There's also uncacheable memory regions: a load or store to uncacheable memory is architecturally "direct", but in the actually microarchitecture it still goes through the memory hierarchy from the load/store execution unit through the same mechanism that L1D uses to talk to the memory controller.