# While pipelining, can you consecutively write mov to the same register, or does it require 3 NOPs like add does?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

This is the correct way to implement mov and add through x86 when incorporating pipelining and the necessary NOPs you need.

```
 mov $10, eax
 NOP 
 NOP
 NOP
 add $2, eax
```

If I wanted to change eax with mov, could I immedietely overwrite it with another mov since you're just overwriting what is already there, or do I need to write 3 NOPs again so it can finish the WMEDF cycle?

```
mov $10, eax
mov $12, eax
```

or

```
mov $10, eax
NOP
NOP
NOP
mov $12, eax
```

Comment: You understand the `NOP`s aren't necessary in either case, right? The CPU is aware of instruction dependencies and will ensure the `add` doesn't read the value from `eax` (or an intermediate stage of the `mov` itself) before the `mov` info is available. This isn't Itanium, where the compiler *must* account for instruction dependencies. As for overwriting one `mov` with another, I'd assume no dependencies (one just overwrites the other), but I'm not a hardware guy. How is the tagged `c`? There is no C code here.

Comment: I'm learning about this stuff in an optimization lab through c, but true language doesn't matter in this case so I'll take it off. So you think 2 movs are technically faster than an mov and an add assuming the register is the same at the end?

Comment: Maybe? I suspect in practice modern chips may execute them both in the same amount of time; the partial results of the `mov` may be available to the `add` before `eax` is actually populated; for example, [on Skylake](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf#page=231) `mov` of an immediate to a register appears to be a latency 1 instruction in a dependency chain, as is `add` where the destination is a register and the other operand is register or immediate. But if the double `mov` doesn't induce a dependency chain (I suspect it wouldn't), then perhaps the overall latency is 1 vs. 2?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes (other than code-size effects on the front-end: **see http://agner.org/optimize/**), two `mov` instructions are faster than `mov` / `add`.  As you say, the first `mov` isn't part of the dependency chain started by the 2nd `mov`.  AFAIK, even in-order CPUs like P5 pentium or Atom (pre-Silvermont) are fine with this.

Comment: The only exception is of course writing to partial registers (like `mov $1, %al`), which merges into the old value on Haswell/Skylake (and on all CPUs other than Intel P6-family and maybe Sandybridge, where `al` can be renamed separately from the rest of `rax`).  See [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to) for my investigation of partial-register performance / dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This is the correct way to implement mov and add through x86 when incorporating pipelining and the necessary NOPs you need.

Totally incorrect for x86.  NOP is *never* needed for correctness on x86<sup>1</sup>.

If an input isn't ready for an instruction, it waits for it to be ready.  (Out-of-order execution can hide this waiting for multiple dependency chains in parallel...

I think I've read that some architectures has some instructions where you get unpredictable values if you read the results too soon.  That's only for a few instructions (like maybe multiply), and many architectures don't have any cases where NOPs (or useful work on other registers) are architecturally required.

Normal cases (like cache-miss loads) on simple in-order pipelines are handled with [pipeline interlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Solution_B._Pipeline_interlock) that effectively insert NOPs in hardware if required, without requiring software to contain useless instructions that will slow down high-performance (out-of-order) implementations of the same architecture running the same binaries.

---

> or do I need to write 3 NOPs again so it can finish the WMEDF cycle?

The x86 ISA wasn't designed around the [classic RISC pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline) (if that's what that abbreviation is supposed to indicate).  So even scalar in-order pipelined x86 implementations like i486 which are internally similar to what you're thinking of have to handle code that doesn't use NOPs to create delays.  i.e. they have to detect data dependencies themselves.

Of course, modern x86 implementations are all at least 2-wide superscalar (old Atom pre-Silvermont, or first-gen Xeon Phi, or P5 Pentium).  Those CPUs are in-order, but others are out-of-order with full register renaming (Tomasulo's algorithm), **which avoids Write-After-Write hazards** like the one you're talking about.  For example, Skylake can run

```
mov   $10, %eax
mov   $11, %eax
mov   $12, %eax
mov   $13, %eax
...
eventually jcc to make a loop
```

at 4 `mov` instructions per cycle, even though they all write the same register.

But note that `mov $1, %al` merges into `%rax` on CPUs other than Intel P6-family (PPro/PII to Core2/Nehalem), and maybe Sandybridge (but not later CPUs like Haswell).  On those CPUs with partial-register renaming for the low 8, `mov $1, %al` can run a multiple instructions per cycle (limited by ALU ports).  But on others, it's like an `add` to `%rax`.  See [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to).  (Fun fact, repeated `mov %bl, %ah` runs 4 per clock on Skylake, repeated `mov $123, %ah` runs 1 per clock.)

---

Further reading:

- [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction) Register renaming on x86 use Tomasulo's algorithm, and this is a case where the OP's code was slow because they were avoiding register reuse, not leaving enough registers for accumulators to hide the latency of FP add / FMA.
- [Deoptimizing a program for the pipeline in Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-program-for-the-pipeline-in-intel-sandybridge-family-cpus) My answer says a bit more about the lack of WAW and WAR hazards on modern x86, including for memory.

---

Footnotes:

1. In an exploit where you don't know the exact jump target address, a NOP sled can be required for correctness so that a jump anywhere in the area will execute NOPs until it reaches your payload.

Comment: In hindsight, the OP was probably taking a course that used x86 instead of the usual MIPS to talk about a hypothetical pipeline without bypass forwarding in a classic 5-stage RISC pipeline (fetch / decode / exec / memory / write-back).  And perhaps talking about pipeline bubbles created by stalls, not actual NOPs in the machine code, unless they're talking about a hypothetical machine without interlocks.  So no actual x86 at all, just using its instruction names.  Real CPUs always do bypass forwarding because the amount of stills would be disastrous as illustrated by exercises like this.