# What is WAW Hazard?

Tags: assembly, pipeline, cpu-architecture, microprocessors

> **Wikipedia's [Hazard (computer architecture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Write_after_write_(WAW)) article:**
>
> Write after write (WAW) (`i2` tries to write an operand before it is
>   written by `i1`) A write after write (WAW) data hazard may occur in a
>   concurrent execution environment.
>
> Example For example:
>
> ```
> i1. R2 <- R4 + R7   
> i2. R2 <- R1 + R3
> ```
>
> The write back (WB) of `i2` must be
>   delayed until `i1` finishes executing.

I haven't understood this.

What is the problem if `i2` is executed before `i1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both operations affect `R2`. If `i2` write back occurs before the write back of `i1`, but the write back of `i1` does eventually occur, then `R2` will have the result of `R4 + R7` instead of the value of `R1 + R3`.

The WAW Hazard is about result values being overwritten by a subsequent write that should not have overwritten that value.

Answer (score 6):

It's not *execution* that's the problem; it's only write-back that prevents out-of-order execution of these instructions (if you didn't do register renaming).

The final result in `R2` (as seen by other later instructions *after* this pair) has to match program order, so it has to have the result of the 2nd instruction.

---

**This is *why* modern out-of-order execution CPUs use register renaming (Tomasulo's algorithm)** instead of just scoreboarding: it totally negates WAW and WAR hazards.  See the first section of my answer on [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction) for another explanation in theoretical terms of how register renaming makes reuse of the same register for different results not a problem.

Also see [Deoptimizing a program for the pipeline in Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-program-for-the-pipeline-in-intel-sandybridge-family-cpus) where I also explain that WAW and WAR anti-dependencies can't cause stalls on modern out-of-order execution CPUs.

For writes to memory (instead of registers), the store buffer takes care of hiding WAW and WAR hazards.